# Viewing the same Applet on multiple clients

Tags: java, networking, applet, client

I have been trying to figure out how i would go about letting multiple clients view the same Applet on Java. I have the code for the the server and the clients and i have a program that I would like them to view. However whenever i test the code I end up with the clients seeing the same program but different instances of it. I want them both to be able to see the same program and see when the other clients make action on the Applet and what not. It would just be for a local connection and I don't have any HTML files at this time.

Comment: You may want to look at a (https://vaadin.com/home) and there is some samples here (https://app.box.com/s/oo6lbhx85lwkm7avd21o)

Comment: What you're asking for is a web-based remote collaboration system.  There are products like TeamViewer or other desktop-sharing that do this for the entire desktop, but I don't know if there is one that runs inside a browser and can share arbitrary applets.  The applets themselves would need to include the UI-sharing capability mediated by the server.

Comment: Since the applet runs in the VM of the client, each client needs a JRE, and each applet instance will necessarily be distinct (unique).